Do I need bigquery.readsessions.create permission to read data with SQLAlchemy?
Does anyone know how to approach READING data from the tables already existing in GCP? I want to use SQLAlchemy ORM and the dialect is BigQuery.
I have tried different approaches, like reflecting (it seems not to work because the existing tables don't have primary keys). Right now I try creating a Table object locally with autoload_with=my_engine. Table seems to get created locally (with schema set to None) but when I try to execute select() on it I get permission error: {PermissionDenied}PermissionDenied("request failed: the user does not have 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permission for 'projects/my-project-name' It gets thrown on calling create_read_session in big_query_read/client.py (a module in big_query_storage).
According to docs:

I've noticed that I need to have this permission in order to interact with the data via ORM but I can successfully execute raw SQL queries. So I can interact with the same table via SQL and don't need a read session create permission.
So basically this returns the expected result without the permission:
from sqlalchemy import text
conn.execute(text("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;"))

while this requires the permission:
conn.execute(MyTable.select())
I cannot change anything in GCP, including user permissions.
I don't know if it clarifies anything, but I get the table like that:
table = Table('project.dataset.table', metadata, autoload_with=engine) --> and the created table has a ReadOnlyColumnCollection with all the columns.
I would appreciate some hint of some workaround cause I wouldn't like to use raw SQL queries :)

Try removing the 'google-cloud-bigquery-storage' package if you have it installed.
